# C++ std::barrier as class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, barrier

How do you store an `std::barrier` as a class member,

Because the completion function can be a lambda, you can't type it properly, and using an `std::function< void(void) noexcept >` won't work either as `std::function` does not seem to support the `noexcept` keyword.

So it seems there is no generic base type for `std::barrier` completion functions

Small example

```
#include <barrier>

struct Storage
{
    std::barrier< ?? > barrier;
}
```

Comment: For lambdas, from C++20 onwards you can write lambdas within unevaluated contexts such as `decltype`, allowing you to write `std::barrier<decltype([]() noexcept { /* logic */ })> barrier;`.

Comment: "*Because the completion function can be a lambda*" Then don't make it a lambda. The lambda police will not pull you over if you use a named type. This is a problem purely of your own making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Warning: this answer contains errors

You can put a type-erasing `CompletionFunction` into `std::barrier` even though it lacks adapting constructors.  It may require an extra bit of casting.

You may have to use a move-only type erasing function due to the various requirements that `std::barrier` places on its `CompletionFunction`.

Note that `std::barrier` does not support assigning - using smart-storage (unique ptr seems best) might fix any issues you have here.  The semantics of the wrapping structure get complex regardless of which you use.  Note that copying a barrier is semantically nonsense; moving a barrier could make sense.

## Original, over-complex answer:

`std::barrier` does not support polymorphic `CompletionFunction` types/values -- it doesn't have the adapting constructors found in some other types.  So using `std::function` in there is a non-starter, regardless of its support -- two `std::barrier`s with different `CompletionFunction` types are unrelated, and cannot be assigned to each other.

You could type erase it yourself, and write a `poly_barrier`.  The barrier (pun intended) to doing this is that `arrival_token` doesn't seem to support polymorphism; there may be no guarantee it is the same type in different `std::barrier<X>` cases.

It is MoveConstructible, MoveAssignable and Destructible however, so we could type erase *it* as well.

First API sketch:

```
struct poly_barrier;
struct poly_barrier_vtable;
struct poly_arrival_token:private std::unique_ptr<void> {
  friend struct poly_barrier_vtable;
  poly_arrival_token(poly_arrival_token&&)=default;
  private:
    explicit poly_arrival_token(std::unique_ptr<void> ptr):
      poly_arrival_token(std::move(ptr))
    {}
};
struct poly_barrier_vtable;

struct poly_barrier {
  template<class CF>
  poly_barrier( std::ptrdiff_t expected, CF cf );
  ~poly_barrier();
  poly_barrier& operator=(poly_barrier const&)=delete;
  poly_arrival_token arrive( std::ptrdiff_t n = 1 );
  void wait( poly_arrival_token&& ) const;
  void arrive_and_wait();
  void arrive_and_drop();
private:
  poly_barrier_vtable const* vtable = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<void> state;
};
```

we now write up a vtable:

```
struct poly_barrier_vtable {
  void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;
  poly_arrival_token(*arrive)(void*, std::ptrdiff_t) = 0;
  void(*wait)(void const*, poly_arrival_token&& ) = 0;
  void(*arrive_and_wait)(void*) = 0;
  void(*arrive_and_drop)(void*) = 0;
private:
  template<class CF>
  static poly_arrival_token make_token( std::barrier<CF>::arrival_token token ) {
    return poly_arrival_token(std::make_unique<decltype(token)>(std::move(token)));
  }
  template<class CF>
  static std::barrier<CF>::arrival_token extract_token( poly_arrival_token token ) {
    return std::move(*static_cast<std::barrier<CF>::arrival_token*>(token.get()));
  }
protected:
  template<class CF>
  poly_barrier_vtable create() {
    using barrier = std::barrier<CF>;
    return {
      +[](void* pb){
         return static_cast<barrier*>(pb)->~barrier();
      },
      +[](void* pb, std::ptrdiff_t n)->poly_arrival_token{
        return make_token<CF>(static_cast<barrier*>(pb)->arrive(n));
      },
      +[](void const* bp, poly_arrival_token&& token)->void{
        return static_cast<barrier const*>(pb)->wait( extract_token<CF>(std::move(token)) );
      },
      +[](void* pb)->void{
        return static_cast<barrier*>(pb)->arrive_and_wait();
      },
      +[](void* pb)->void{
        return static_cast<barrier*>(pb)->arrive_and_drop();
      }
    };
  }
public:
  template<class CF>
  poly_barrier_vtable const* get() {
    static auto const table = create<CF>();
    return &table;
  }
};
```

which we then use:

```
struct poly_barrier {
  template<class CF>
  poly_barrier( std::ptrdiff_t expected, CF cf ):
    vtable(poly_barrier_vtable<CF>::get()),
    state(std::make_unique<std::barrier<CF>>( expected, std::move(cf) ))
  {}
  ~poly_barrier() {
    if (vtable) vtable->dtor(state.get());
  }
  poly_barrier& operator=(poly_barrier const&)=delete;
  poly_arrival_token arrive( std::ptrdiff_t n = 1 ) {
    return vtable->arrive( state.get(), n );
  }
  void wait( poly_arrival_token&& token ) const {
    return vtable->wait( state.get(), std::move(token) );
  }
  void arrive_and_wait() {
    return vtable->arrive_and_wait(state.get());
  }
  void arrive_and_drop() {
    return vtable->arrive_and_drop(state.get());
  }
private:
  poly_barrier_vtable const* vtable = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<void> state;
};
```

and bob is your uncle.

There are probably typos above.  It also doesn't support moving arbitrary barriers into it; adding a ctor should make that easy.

All calls to `arrive` involve a memory allocation, and all calls to `wait` deallocation due to not knowing what an `arrival_token` is; in theory, we could create a on-stack type erased token with a limited size, which I might do if I was using this myself.

`arrive_and_wait` and `arrive_and_drop` do not use heap allocation.  You can drop `arrive` and `wait` if you don't need them.

Everything bounces through a manual vtable, so there are going to be some performance hits.  You'll have to check if they are good enough.

I know this technique as C++ value-style type erasure, where we manually implement polymorphism in a C-esque style, but we automate the type erasure generation code using C++ templates.  It will become far less ugly when we have compile time reflection in the language (knock on wood), and is the kind of thing you might do to implement `std::function`.

The code blows up in fun ways if you pass arrival tokens from one barrier to another.  But so does `std::barrier`, so that seems fair.

---

A completely different approach, with amusingly similar implementation, would be to write a nothrow-on-call `std::function`.

Implementing `std::function` efficiently usually involves something similar to the `vtable` approach above, together with a small buffer optimization (SBO) to avoid memory allocation with small function objects (which I alluded to wanting to do with `poly_arrival_token`).

Comment: What does it mean that it “does not support polymorphic `CompletionFunction` types/values”?  You certainly could use `std::function` explicitly as the type if it weren’t for the `noexcept` bit in the question, and `std::move_only_function` can be used (given an appropriate constructor argument).

Comment: @DavisHerring You are correct - in my head I assumed `CompletionFunction` was a lambda and didn't think about putting the type erasure in there!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example in C++17 using a `std::barrier` object as a class member variable along with the `arrive_and_wait` method for synchronizing multiple threads:

```
#include <barrier>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo{
public:
    explicit Foo(int thCnt) : b(thCnt,[](){}){}
    barrier<void(*)()> b;
    //barrier<function<void()>> b;  //This works also

    void thFun(int thNum){
        printf("thNum: %i\n",thNum);
        b.arrive_and_wait();
    }
};

int main(){
    int numWorkers = 5;
    Foo f(numWorkers + 1); // +1 for the b.arrive_and_wait called in main()
    vector<thread> threadVec(numWorkers);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<numWorkers; ++i){
        threadVec.emplace_back(&Foo::thFun,&f,i);
    }
    f.b.arrive_and_wait(); //barrier waits for all threads to finish.
    for(auto &th : threadVec){
        if(th.joinable()) th.join();
    }
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bard explanation for why a completion function pointer is required when adding an std::barrier to a class while it's not required outside a class. https://g.co/bard/share/d8ea607ee8e5